# How to Assign Background Color Using "if" Condition

Tags: windows-7, openoffice-calc

How can I assign the Background color of a particular Cell in an Open Office? Likewise greater the Somevalues should having Green, and less than value should having Red background?

Answer (score 1):

You need `Format > Conditional Formatting` from the main menubar.

You need to create a named cell format first, then set the conditions under which this format will apply. See [LibreOffice help on this](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Applying_Conditional_Formatting), it works identically in this respect AFAICT (wiki.openoffice.org doesn't have detailed instructions).